# How to use alert dialog when pressing back button?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I want to show alert dialog when pressing back button. But I'm facing a problem.

This is my code:

```
   BackHanlder{
       AlertDialogComponent()
}
```

And I got this error:

> @composable invocations can only happen from the context of an
> @composable function

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To show alert dialog you have to keep the boolean value as state, and change it in back handler

```
var showAlertDialog by remember { mutableStateOf(false)}
    BackHandler {
        showAlertDialog = true
    }
    if(showAlertDialog){
        AlertDialog(//)
    }
```